# Осциллограф. JavaFX. Доступ к классу-контроллеру. Потоки взаимодействие потоков.

Tags: controller, потоки-данных, javafx

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу написать примитивный осциллограф с использованием arduino и JavaFX. В процессе разработки всплыл ряд проблем:

1) Мне нужно обновлять график на форме бесконечно, поэтому необходимо получить доступ к объекту графика из другого класса(не из fx:controller="arduino.Controller). Погуглив понял, что можно получить доступ [таким образом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class) Разобраться с этим не получилось.

2) Необходимо получать значения из ком порта [таким образом](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java) Проблема заключается в том, что создается поток, из которого я не могу передавать значения потоку JavaFx. Может с помощью синхронизированных переменных?

Прошу привести наглядные примеры кода. Просидел вчера весь день, теперь уповаю на вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Yuri_Prime, да, вылетает Exception Not in FX thread, попробую. Не могли бы вы привести более детальный пример для первого, в javafx я недавно. Спасибо.

Comment: @palyla, обновил ответ, смотрите

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, теперь разберусь, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну со второго. Если у вас вылетает Exception Not in FX thread - используйте конструкцию Platform.runLater(Runnable r), передайте ей объект Runnable и он будет выполнен в потоке FX. Я сам с этим мучился. Если я правильно понял, любая работа с объектами JavaFX должна происходить только в FX-потоках.
Относительно первого - я, когда создаю интерфейс, создаю ещё один дополнительный класс-модель со всеми нужными мне Property и необходимыми методами получения самого объекта Property, а так же геттер и сеттер - на каждую Property по 3 метода. А затем просто привязываю Property объекта с Property модели. Например:

```
<DataModel fx:id="dataModel/>
...
<LineChart>
...
<data>
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
<Series.Data data="${dataModel.chartData}"/>
</FXCollections>
</data>
</LineChart>
```

В итоге здесь получается доступ не к самому графику, а к объекту, который отвечает за набор данных в этом графике.
Разумеется, в классе DataModel должно быть Property подходящего типа. И ещё - следите за импортами в FXML-файлах - в Eclipse, например, он автоматически не импортирует классы String, FXCollections, Series.Data и прочее, надо прописывать импорт руками.

Более детально, класс DataModel:

```
ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Data<Integer, Integer>>>> channelData1 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "dataChannel1", FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public final ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Data<Integer, Integer>>> dataChannel1Property(){ return this.channelData1; }

public final ObservableList<Data<Integer, Integer>> getDataChannel1(){
    return this.channelData1.get();
}

public void setDataChannel1(ObservableList<Data<Integer, Integer>> newValue){
    this.channelData1.set(newValue);
}
```

Файл MainStage.fxml, часть отвечающая за график:

```
<fx:define>
<DataModel fx:id="model"/>
</fx:define>
...
<LineChart title="Канал 1" legendVisible="false" createSymbols="false">
<xAxis>
<NumberAxis lowerBound="0" upperBound="4096" tickUnit="100" autoRanging="false" label="Код АЦП"/>
</xAxis>
<yAxis>
<NumberAxis label="Число событий" autoRanging="true"/>
</yAxis> 
<data>
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
<XYChart.Series data="${model.dataChannel1}"/>
</FXCollections>
</data>
</LineChart>
```

Здесь у меня создавался график с одной серией данных, разумеется, можно добавить в раздел data графика ещё серий и создать для них нужные Property в модели. Класс-контроллер так же будет иметь доступ к классу-модели